# How to make splash screen like pinterest android application?

Tags: android, dynamic-splash-screen

I am developing android application and initially I need to describe what is my app is all about.

I like the way Pinterest is doing, operating a UI thread with background animation. Another example is Snapchat, on login page front camera is running with display of textview and all.

Comment: What is your question? Edit your description to make it become a question.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pinterest&hl=en please download this app and run..I wanted to make first screen like same as pinterest

Comment: You still provide no question

Comment: my question is how to make splash screen dynamic, I want to learn how to animate images on background and on same time I wanted to display Textview and Buttons, and Position of buttons and textview should not change while background animation of images start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start reading these documentations and tutorials:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html
- http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/imageview-animation-in-android.html